# Could not install packages using Yum

Tags: centos7, yum

I have checked my DNS configuration and made sure address is resolving.But when I tried to install package I am getting following error.

OS : centos 7.3.1611

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:4178:5:200::10: Network is unreachable"

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64

please guide me.

Comment: Its trying to make an IPv6 connection and failing (`2001:4178:5:200::10: Network is unreachable`) - are you setup for IPv6 networking?

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment, it was something to do with my client's network configuration.After they fixed yum is working fine.

Comment: kindly check your internet service